# Use nested layouts in Middleman

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

I'm basically work with Middleman 2 though if this can only be done in Middleman 3 I can switch to it

I have `layout.haml` having all the boilerplate and simultaneously being the index's layout.

Now I want the `inner.haml` layout that will work for the rest of the pages, will *inherit* from `layout.haml` (in terms that I won't repeat the boilerplate parts), will incude some extra common styles / scripts, some common markup and will then re-place the `yield` blocks.

Currently I don't realize at all from where should I start. I understand how I can set `inner.haml` as a default layout and `layout.haml` as a layout for the "/" route, but how would the system know that the `inner.haml` is actually nested within `layout.haml`?

*Sample setup*

*layout.haml*

```
!!!5
%html
  %head
    %script(src="HTML5 shiv")
    %title
      My Site
      \|
      = yield_content :title
    = stylesheet_link_tag "site.css"
    = yield_content :page_styles
  %body
    %div(role="main")
      = yield_content :content
    %script(src="jquery")
    = yield_content :page_scripts
```

*index.html.haml*

```
- content_for :title do
  Index
- content_for :page_styles do
  = stylesheet_link_tag "index.css"
- content_for :page_scripts do
  %script(src="index.js")
- content_for :content do
  Cool banner here
```

*inner.haml*

```
-# somehow inherits from / extends layout.haml
- content_for :page_styles do
  -# somehow I'm putting some common content and then reinclude the block from the specific page
  = stylesheet_link_tag "inner.css"
  = yield_content :page_styles
-# same thing for page_scripts
- content_fir :content do
  -# again I define some common HTML, then include page's content
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3.0 you'd have `index` use the layout `inner` which would `wrap_layout` `layout`.

In 2.0, you'll need a combination of partials and `content_for` blocks.

Comment: I'm using content_for and yield_content already. When saying partials you mean that I should put all common_inner_styles, common_inner_scripts and common_inner_markup into separate partials? I would be fine with that, but is it possible to put content inside of the partial? I mean I want some common wrapper elements for all of the inner pages custom contents

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I'd be tempted to do this with two templates. Perhaps not as elegant or DRY, but certainly understandable and easy to tweak later. E.g. for our site we have a [front page layout](https://github.com/agamz/FindBigMail-old/blob/master/source/floating_content_with_logo_layout.haml) and a [rest of the site layout](https://github.com/agamz/FindBigMail-old/blob/master/source/floating_content_without_logo_layout.haml). And then in each MiddleMan source file we declare which layout will be used ([see example](https://github.com/agamz/FindBigMail-old/blob/master/source/localizable/about_us.html.haml)).

All that aside, I'm hoping to learn something from a HAML master who has some magic for your situation!

Comment: yes, definitely not dry. what I really have - the all-site template (not so tiny) and then some more common markup for every inner page. so I definitely don't wont any repetition here